# How to set a load event for images on a complex Object in javascript

Tags: javascript, load

I'm loading a lot of images in javascript that are going to be needed in very different contexts. To easily access them in different contexts I created a tree-kind-of object. Something like this:

```
var imgs = {
  scene: new Image(),
  character1 :{
    left: {
       stand: new Image(),
       kick: new Image(),
       ...
    }
    right: {
       stand: new Image(),
       kick: new Image(),
       ...
    }
  character2 :{
    left: {
       stand: new Image(),
       kick: new Image(),
       ...
    }
    right: {
       stand: new Image(),
       kick: new Image(),
       ...
    }
}
```

Then I loaded the images:

```
imgs.scene.src = "scene.jpg";
imgs.character1.left.stand.src = "char1stand.png";
imgs.character1.left.kick.src = "char1kick.png";
...
```

Now I want to make a reliable method to attach an event to them. But the problem is the amount of levels I have. Is there a way of doing this without going into a complex system of for-in loops?

Comment: You want all images having the same onload-event handler ?

Comment: Yes, they should call a function that adds 1 to the imagesLoaded variable and evals if all of them are loaded (it is a preloader)
I'd also accept an event that is called only once when all of them are loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want the handler being the same for all, you can set it up when you create the images.

```
var imagesLoaded = 0,
    total = 50; // set the total amount of images you have

function allLoaded() { /* do some stuff when all images are loaded */ };

function loaded() { // handler attached to all images
    // increase counter, if total is reached call allLoaded handler
    if (++imagesLoaded == total) allLoaded();
    /* do some more stuff */
}

function createImg() {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = loaded;
    return img;
}
```

Now replace  in your `imgs` object all `new Image()` with `createImg()`.

Comment: I was about to check this is a valid answer... but!
I can't call createImg() when I construct the object literal.

Comment: @user3633687 Why not ? It's just a call like `new Image()`.

Comment: I'm so sorry! I did it again and it worked, I don't know what I did before but this surely works! Great solution, btw! :)